# Is there a handy way to pass function arguments to initialize a Dictionary(of string,string) in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, initialization, convenience-methods

We can do this in vb.net:

```
Dim d= new Dictionary(of string, string) from {{"a","valA"},{"b","valB"}}
```

Please how can we make the following possible for convenience:

```
public sub Setup(args)
   Dim d= new Dictionary(of string, string) from args
end sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the type of `args`, preferably?

Comment: No, you can't initialize a dictionary with collection initializer syntax from a variable or parameter. It's just syntactic sugar that the compiler _eats_ if you assign it in the way you've shown in the first snippet. However, you can pass an `IDictionary(Of String, String)` and use that for the constructor of the dictionary. Or you can pass an `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))` and use that for `args.ToDictionary(Function(kv) kv)`. The former approach is more efficient, the latter is more general.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that sucks... the initializer convenience would have made all the difference

Comment: I think second Tim's solution is easyest .. KeyValuePair

Comment: @CharlesO: Why? What do you want to pass as parameter at all? Every methiod parameter has a concrete type, what do you want to pass to initialze a dictionary?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i was thinking simple {{"",""},....}

Comment: @TimSchmelter that would simply be string ()()

Comment: @CharlesO: That's neither a type nor valid syntax (taken by itself).

Comment: @TimSchmelter i get what you are saying. i felt if i can write this: `Dim d= new Dictionary(of string, string) from {{"a","valA"},{"b","valB"}}` then the from part could be made into a variable. but you have pointed out that is is just syntactic sugar...sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't initialize a dictionary with collection initializer syntax from a variable or parameter. It's just syntactic sugar that the compiler eats if you assign it in the way you've shown in the first snippet.

However, you can pass an `IDictionary(Of String, String)` and use that for the constructor of the dictionary:

```
Public sub Setup(dict As IDictionary(Of String, String))
   Dim d = new Dictionary(Of String, String)( dict )
End Sub
```

Or you can pass an `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))` and use that for `args.ToDictionary(Function(kv) kv)`:

```
Public sub Setup(keyVals As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)))
   Dim d = args.ToDictionary(Function(kv) kv)
End Sub
```

The former approach is more efficient, the latter is more general. Allowing `IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` has the advantage that you can pass more types since there are [many classes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/idictionary.cs,20343df0c96b629b,references) that implement that interface.

Comment: Question: is this a vb.net limitation? does c# offer an alternative?

Comment: @CharlesO: no, in C# it's also not possible. But again, i don't know what you have in mind. `{{"a","valA"},{"b","valB"}}` is not a tye and not valid syntax if not used directly as collection initializer for a dictionary.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify an API which requires initializing a dictionary(of string,string). IT becomes very tedious to keep passng new Dictionary(of string, string) from {{"a","valA"},{"b","valB"},....} as arguments each time the the function is called , and it is used a lot.

Comment: @CharlesO: why don't you reuse the dictionary instead of always creating a new one? It's not clear what the input is, if it's a collection you could also use LINQ's `ToDictionary`.